# How to get the root site collection from a web application?

Tags: timer-jobs

I am using sharepoint 2010 with some custom timer job at web application scope. In this timer job I have a foreach which loops into all site collection in the current web application. There is an if where I check if there is some custom feature activated. I would like to change this code. It needs to check this only on the root site collection of the web application. Not the sub site collections. How can I do this?

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
    {
        try
        {
            DiagnosticsService.LogMessage(this.Title + " - Started", 0, DiagnosticsCategory.Jobs);

            var webApplication = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
            if (webApplication == null)
            {
                DiagnosticsService.LogError("Web application not found", 0, DiagnosticsCategory.Jobs);
                return;
            }

            foreach (var site in webApplication.Sites.ToList())
            {
                try
                {
                    // TODO 1 : check if this is the root site collection of the web application
                    if (site.Features[ProfileTranslationListsDefinitionFeatureId] != null)
                    {
                        this.ProcessProfiles(site);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (site != null)
                    {
                        site.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: There are no such thing as a Root Site Collection, there is really no relations at all between different site collections. Do you mean the site collection that has the same URL as your DNS entry?

Comment: Maybe you are confusing Root Site Collection with the "/" site collection that is a Top Level Site Collection.

Comment: If I have a web application with this url "http://portal.mycompany.com" then I see the root site collection. Inside this site collection I can add a sub site collection for example "http://portal.mycompany.com/location/amsterdam". This sub site collection I dont want to get. I would like to get only the root site collection.

Answer (score 5):

You can use LINQ to filter the Sites collection on the web application.  Something like:

```
webApp.Sites.Where(p => p.ServerRelativeUrl.Equals("/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```